# Create Log function

Tags: functions, logarithms

I'm a programmer. I'm working with a sensor that has given the following graph.
I would like to make a function where i put the value of Rs/R0 in. The outcome of this function is the value of ppm of alcohol.

I understand that precision is imposible so, for the function i'm going for a straigt line from point (200 , 2.9 ) and the second point would be (10000 , 0.68).

I tried to google how you create log functions but i got stuck with the problem that i don't know the value of y (in my case rs/r0) when x (in my case ppm) is 1 . All tuts online i found used that. Is there an other way to calculate the function?

[image]

Comment: If you don't formalize your question in a more mathematical way, then it might be hard to get help from this site...

Comment: The relationship here is $\log(y) = A\log(x) + B$. You only need two points $(x_1,y_1)$  and $(x_2,y_2)$ on the curve to determine $A$ and $B$. This gives you the two equations $\log(y_1) = A\log(x_1) + B$ and $\log(y_2) = A\log(x_2) + B$ that you can use to solve for $A$ and $B$ and then you have the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your graph $\frac {R_s}{R_0}$ is a logarithmic function of the concentration in ppm.  You want to go the other way, so your function will be exponential.  You are fitting a line through two points, which you do by choosing your functional form and evaluating the coefficients.  If you choose your form to be $\log_{10} \frac {R_s}{R_0}=a+b\log_{10}(c)$ where $c$ is the concentration in ppm.  Each point gives one equation in $a,b$.  You have two equations in two unknowns.
$$0.46=a+b\cdot 2.30\\
-0.70=a+b\cdot 4\\
-1.16=1.70b\\
b=-1.47\\
a=5.16$$
You can raise $10$ to the power of each side, getting
$$\frac {R_s}{R_0}=10^a\cdot c^b=145000c^{-1.47}$$
where I have shown too many significant figures so you can follow through the calculation.